# How to melt my data to create a bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I would like to create a bar chart using ggplot that compares the duration of different activities. On the y axis I would like to have time in hours and minutes and on x axis activities-labels.

What I am struggling with is how to transform my data and how to convert into time format.

At this moment time is represented in 10 minutes intervals eg. 460 /60 = 7 hours and 40 minutes

My data format is below:

```
structure(list(Sleep = c(460, 420, 500, 600, 280, 700, 420, 500, 
600, 460), `Tv and video` = c(200, 60, 140, 120, 0, 300, 80, 
210, 140, 340), `Main job` = c(0, 0, 500, 0, 420, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `Social life` = c(210, 260, 60, 20, 40, 0, 410, 180, 160, 
70), Eating = c(90, 80, 50, 120, 90, 60, 120, 90, 60, 120), `Travel by purpose` = c(180, 
140, 0, 60, 190, 10, 70, 70, 100, 140), `Other personal care` = c(60, 
70, 40, 30, 90, 60, 130, 60, 0, 140), `Food management` = c(110, 
190, 10, 90, 0, 40, 0, 70, 90, 20), `Radio and music` = c(0, 
0, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0), `Childcare of own household member` = c(30, 
50, 80, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 140, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
df %>% 
  gather(k, v) %>% 
  mutate(v=v/60) %>% 
  mutate(k = gsub(" ", "\n", k)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(k,-v), v)) + 
   geom_col() +
   ylab("Hours") + xlab("Activities")
```

[image]

Text can be added using this

```
df %>% 
  gather(k, v) %>% 
  mutate(k = gsub(" ", "\n", k)) %>% 
  group_by(k) %>% 
  summarise(v=sum(v)/60) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(k,-v), v, label = round(v,1))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(nudge_y = 2) +
  ylab("Hours") + xlab("Activities")
```

Comment: many thanks for your time what I don't understand is the y axis what means rthe 400000? is 400000 minutes? and how can i convert into hours and minute

Comment: @user11964604 please reload the page. I edited my answer a little bit.

Comment: many thanks for your time one question is there a way to display the hours on the stacked bar. For example on top of the sleep 83 and so on?

Comment: of course. check `geom_text` function and add `label = v` to the `aes()`. but prior, you have to summarize. I edit my answer.

Comment: @jimbou Looks like the extra polish gives you the cake, though I was a few minutes faster that you with the full solution with a graph ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can first gather your data columns into long format with the two columns "class" and "value". Then you can sum the values by class. Finally you can make a barplot, where you use the values directly (stat = "identity"). The theme rotates the axis of the lables on the x-axis.

```
# Libraries
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Gathering, summarizing and plotting data
data %>% 
  gather("class", "value", 1:10) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(class, total)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: in the case of  `stat = "identity"` it is recommended to use `geom_col`

Comment: @esbeneickhardt many thanks for your time what I don't understand is the y axis what means rthe 400000? is 400000 minutes? and hjow can i convert into hours and minutes?